# Limits of Expectations

Tags: probability-theory, limits

I've been fighting with this homework problem for a while now, and I can't quite see the light.  The problem is as follows,

> Assume random variable $X \ge 0$, but do NOT assume that $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac1{X}\right] < \infty$.  Show that $$\lim_{y \to 0^+}\left(y \, \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{X} ; X > y\right]\right) = 0$$

After some thinking, I've found that I can bound

$$
\mathbb{E}[1/X;X>y] =  
\int_y^{\infty}\frac1{x}\mathrm dP(x) \le 
\int_y^{\infty}\frac1{y}\mathrm dP(x)
$$

since $\frac1{y} = \sup\limits_{x \in (y, \infty)} \frac1{x}$ resulting in

$$
\lim_{y \to 0^+} y \mathbb{E}[1/X; X>y] \le 
\lim_{y \to 0^+} y \int_y^{\infty}\frac1{y}\mathrm dP(x) = P[X>0]\le1
$$

Of course, $1 \not= 0$.  I'm not really sure how to proceed...

**EDIT:** $\mathbb{E}[1/X;X>y]$ is defined to be $\int_y^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}\mathrm dP(x)$.  This is the notation used in Durret's *Probability: Theory and Examples*.  It is NOT a conditional expectation, but rather a specifier of what set is being integrated over.

**EDIT:** Changed $\lim_{y \rightarrow 0^-}$ to $\lim_{y \rightarrow 0^+}$; this was a typo.

Comment: It's not a good idea for titles to be entirely in $\TeX$.

Comment: Srivatsan, J.M.: fixed!

Comment: @J.M. Interesting. Why is full title in TeX discouraged?

Comment: To take myself as an example, @Sri, I browse questions by right-clicking on them to open in new tabs. Having the title entirely in $\TeX$ brings up the MathJax menu instead of the browser's popup menu, which interferes with this. Having a text portion allows you to have a place where right-clicking gives the browser's popup menu.

Comment: @Sri yup, typo.  Thanks for catching!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint(s)** For every positive $y$, let $Z_y=(y/X)\mathbf{1}(y/X<1)$. You want to prove that $E(Z_y)\to0$ when $y\to0^+$.

It happens that $0\le Z_y<1$ with full probability, for every positive $y$, and that $Z_y\to0$ when $y\to0^+$ with full probability. (Of course you should check this.)

Now, your goal is to find a condition on a given family of nonnegative random variables $(T_y)$ that ensures that $$\lim\limits_{y\to0^+}E(T_y)=E\left(\lim\limits_{y\to0^+}T_y\right)$$ and to check that your family $(Z_y)$ fulfills this condition. 
There should not exist so many conditions of this ilk in your textbook...

Comment: Got it!  Thanks (again) @Didier!

Comment: @duck, you are welcome.

Comment: @duckworthd Now that you solved the problem, could you mention what condition that is ? Thanks

Comment: @Sasha, either bounded or dominated convergence should work here.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For any $k > 1$, $\int_y^\infty \frac{y}{x} \ dP(x) \le \int_y^{ky}\  dP(x) + \int_{ky}^\infty \frac{1}{k} \ dP(x) \le \ldots$

Comment: Hm... If I could split the limit into 2 ($\lim_{y \rightarrow 0^+} \int_{y}^{ky}dP(x) + \lim_{y \rightarrow 0^+} \int_{ky}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} dP(x)$, one for both integrals, the first would go to 0 as $(y,ky) \rightarrow \emptyset$, but the second still wouldn't necessarily go to 0.  I'm afraid I don't follow...

Comment: The second $\le 1/k$.

Comment: Hmmm...My guess would be that you place a $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}$ outside of $\lim_{y \rightarrow 0^+}$, then let the first integral go to 0 as $y \rightarrow 0$ for fixed $k$, then swap the 2 $\lim$ and let the second integral go to 0 as $k \rightarrow \infty$ for fixed $y$.  That doesn't even seem legal!

Comment: No, you don't swap any limits.  For fixed $k$, when $y > 0$ is small enough your integral $< 2/k$.  Therefore the limit must be $\le 0$.

Comment: Another way is to make the split at $\sqrt{y}$ instead of $ky$.